# Faulty Unity windows resizing keyboard bindings, how do I re-enable them?

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz

Prior to upgrading Ubuntu from Meerkat (10.10), it was possible to put windows on the left or right of the screen using <kbd>Ctl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>Ctl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd>.  Subsequent presses of the same would resize the window from the respective edge outwards.  Needless to say that the feature is mandatory for mouseless window management (try pressing <kbd>Ctl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd> several times to see how useful it can be).

I've checked Compiz settings where Window Management/Grid contains the relevant configurations.  However, I cannot see anything related to cyclic resizing (window placement width).

How can I re-enable this functionality?

Comment: I guess I'm confused by what you mean. For me, the key commands in the Grid section do what you're describing. That is, Ctrl + Alt + KP4 will push the a window to the left half of the screen, and pushing it again will repeat the process.

Comment: @root45 What I mean is that pressing the keys you mentioned will cycle the window through various sizes i.e. the first press sets it to half the screen width, a second press to quarter the screen width, a third to a fifth, a fourth to three quarter screen width.

Since I upgraded, that functionality doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ah I see the issue. At first I thought I didn't have this problem, but I see now that the other directions (put top, put bottom, put center, etc.) all work this way, but for some reason put left and right don't. I would report this as a bug on launchpad.

Comment: It seems to have been reported in a bug report encompassing strange compiz grid behaviour.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/compiz-plugins-main/+bug/862260/comments/4

Comment: Indeed it seems to have been reported as [fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/compiz-plugins-main/+bug/862260/comments/7) in compiz-plugins-main but the fix doesn't seem to have solved the problem.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!